# javascript - Form validation when checking password nothing works

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate a form using javascript but I can change border color when the if statement looking at the password(login_pass) is not included in the script but when added nothing works. I referred to the bootstrap form validation as well but could not understand why nothing works when I add the second if statement with login_pass.

Here is the form html:

```
<form id="needs-validation" name="account" action="" method="POST" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin: auto;">
        <label for="user">User Name</label>
        <input id="login_uname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" value="" name="user" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin: auto;">
        <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        <input id="login_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="" name="pwd" required>
    </div>
        <button id="login_submit" style="margin-right: 10%; float: right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
var login_user = document.getElementById('login_uname');
var login_pass = document.getElementById('login_pass');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    if(login_user.value === "") {
      login_user.style.borderColor = 'red';
    } else {
      login_user.style.borderColor = 'green';
    }
    if(login_pass.value === "") {
      login_pass.style.borderColor = 'red';
    } else {
      login_pass.style.borderColor = 'green';
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var login_pass = document.getElementById('login_pass');
```

to

```
var login_pass = document.getElementById('login_password');
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the typo in the `id` of password field you could use [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) in your syntax like in the example below. It would be better for handling input errors e.g. a pattern mismatch error.

```
var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
var login_user = document.getElementById('login_uname');
var login_pass = document.getElementById('login_password');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
    if (login_user.validity.valueMissing) {
      login_user.style.borderColor = 'red';
    } else {
      login_user.style.borderColor = 'green';
    }          
    if(login_pass.validity.valueMissing) {
      login_pass.style.borderColor = 'red';
    } else {
      login_pass.style.borderColor = 'green';
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }
}, false);
```